# Exception passing parameters to Db2 query in IBM Cloud Functions using Node.js

Tags: node.js, db2, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I wrote a Node.js-based action in IBM Cloud Functions / OpenWhisk. The action retrieves data from Db2. The query works when I don't have parameter markers. When I use a parameter as shown below and pass in `{"confname" : "IDUGEMEA2018" }` then it runs into an error and the exception is raised.

Why? What needs to be changed?

```
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');

function queryConferences(dsn, confname) { 
 try {    
    var conn=ibmdb.openSync(dsn);
    var data=conn.querySync("select shortname, location, begindate, enddate, uri from conference where shortname=?", confname);
    conn.closeSync();
    return {result : data};
 } catch (e) {
     return { dberror : e }
 }
}

function main({confname, __bx_creds: {dashDB:{dsn}}}) {
    return queryConferences(dsn,confname);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the **bindingParameters** is expecting an array. I got it to work passing in the following:

```
{"confname" : ["IDUGEMEA2018"] }
```

In the CLI I tested it with the following:

```
bx wsk action invoke myAction -p confname "[\"IDUGEMEA2018\"]" -r
```